# Why doesn't Netbeans see which of my varargs-method I mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

The code has a problem in line 18  n.fun1("11",1); in netbeans ,but not in other IDE this problem only in NetBeans 7.0.1 the IDE shows:

> reference to fun1 is ambiguous, both method
>   fun1(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...) in Test and method
>   fun1(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.Object...) in Test match

The corresponding code is here:

```
interface Test {
    public void fun1(String str, Object... objs);
    public void fun1(String str, int i, Object... objs);
}
public class NewClass implements Test {
    public void fun1(String str, Object... objs) {
        System.out.println("111111111111111111111");
    }
    public void fun1(String str, int i, Object... objs) {
        System.out.println("2222222222222");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test n = new NewClass();
        n.fun1("11", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please provide the line numbers if you want it that way. 2. Please provide the stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: This looks like a Netbeans bug - it should take the second method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method in your interface `fun1("11", 1); // fun1(String, int)`, try this:

```
n.fun1("11", new Integer(1));
```

Comment: Integer constructor is ineffective, see http://jkingdon2000.blogspot.com/2007/01/new-integer5-versus-integervalueof5.html Use `Integer.valueOf()` instead, as I posted before.

Comment: There is a method which takes a string and an int (and a arbitrary number of objects, including none) - the second one.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated*

After rereading your question I can see the real problem here. There are two `fun1` methods in your interface.

```
public void fun1(String str, Object... objs) // first
```

and

```
public void fun1(String str, int i, Object... objs); // second
```

The problem is, where you're calling the method of your class:

```
n.fun1("11", 1);
```

The IDE could not decide whether you want to call your first method or your second.

Because, it can be the first with autoboxing your `1` parameter to an `Integer` object. Or it can be the second, with the `objs` parameter as an empty array.

There is no way to fix this without modifying your interface. My java compiler (1.6.0_26) can compile it without any problem and it calls your second method.

But as the IDE says it's *ambiguous* and it is right about that, this definition is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: I find it only in netneans 7.0.1

Comment: Actually, not `null` but an empty array.

Comment: thank you, but in fact ,it work in eclipse (work with jdk 5 or jdk 6 update 11).  I think it is netbeans 7.0.1 use some argc to bulid the java source code;

Comment: Yes, because it's valid but confusing. As you can see it confused NetBeans also.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
I found it to be already reported to Netbeans team here : https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200024

Your code should compile with JDK6, but not with JDK7.
According to Netbeans folks, the Java spec does not allow these two methods in a single class.
In their opinion, the fact that JDK6 does not complain about it should be considered as a bug, that has been fixed in JDK7

That's why they answered they would not remove (or make optional) this feature in Netbeans. Even if it looks a bit inconsistent when using JDK6.

In my case, we renamed one of the two methods, so that to be JDK7-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Which JDK is your netbeans using? Could it be an old (really old) one?